# What is the proper way of making a conditional statement with question marks?

Tags: grammar

Say I make a conditional statement, or an either/or statement,

> 1) Do I eat the bananas? Or do I eat the apples?
>
> 2) Do I eat the bananas, or do I eat the apples?

Is it right to add the second question mark like in option 1? How do I punctuate a sentence like this?

Comment: Welcome, Zolani. No need to add your [signature](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) at the end of posts - your username serves as signature and thanks enough, and is a link to your user page :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preferred punctuation depends on how you wish the reader to interpret your thought process, so to speak.

Use two sentences for a complete break in thought to really stress each option:

> Do I eat the bananas? Or do I eat the apples?

Don't even use a comma to make it as casual as possible:

> Do I eat the bananas or apples?

And for a balance, just use a comma:

> Do I eat the bananas, or do I eat the apples?

The comma method and the distinct sentences methods are very similar in my opinion. Neither is wrong.